# jQuery dynamic iframe styling

Tags: jquery, iframe, styling

I want to include some iframes in a web project. Those iframes need to be style to hide navigation bars and such components from the remote site.

I came up with the following code:

```
$.get( "http://www.remotesite.com/data/view.php?id=35", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    $('iframe#test').width('100%');
    $('iframe#test').height('800px');

    $(data).find('header.navbar').css('border', '1px solid red');

    var doc = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(data);
    doc.close();

});
```

What I'm trying to do is load the remote data, hide or style whatever I want in the raw HTML then display it in and iframe with an id of **test**.

The data loads in the iframe but the navbar is not taking the style I attempted to add via: `$(data).find('header.navbar').css('border', '1px solid red');`

Comment: @Rory they are not loading a remote URL into the iframe directly here, but request the content via AJAX, and then write it into the iframe - so the actual iframe content is not cross-domain.

Comment: @CBroe ah yes, you're right. My fault for scan reading the question and code.